# Apply rule to element except if it has ancestor with specific class

Tags: html, css, less

I want a CSS rule to apply to all `<ul>` elements except those who have an ancestor whose class is `editable`, whether that ancestor is their direct parent or no.

The actual type of the ancestor element is not important.
So for instance:

```html
<div>
    <ul> <!-- Apply style here -->
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<figcaption class="editable">
    <div>
        <ul> <!-- No style here-->
            <li>hi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</figcaption>
<figcaption class="editable">
    <ul> <!-- No style either-->
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</figcaption>
```

I've tried:

`*:not(.editable) > ul` ==> rule is not applied to immediate children as desired but is applied on non immediate children

`*:not(.editable) ul` ==> rule is applied to all children

I know I can use `.editable ul` to apply a style to the elements I want but that's not exactly what I want, since what I want to do is prevent the style from being added in the first place.

Comment: why not give the `<ul>` you want to edit an ID?

Comment: This simply can not work for arbitrary nesting levels, using `*:not(.editable) ul` - the `div` in your first `figcaption` element in the example “satisfies” the `*:not(.editable)` part here.